# firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() as int

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

If I use the following command in my firestore:

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

I'm saving the `serverTimestamp` but in a timestamp format. How can I make it so it resembles the same format as a number created by `Date.now()` ?

What I want to accomplish is to save the `serverTimestamp()` but in a plain integer format so basically save the `serverTimestamp` of the firestore in milliseconds - very important.

**EDIT:**

I'm creating a chat app using firestore and my query looks like this:

```
var loadnewmessages = messagesRef.orderBy("timestamp").where("timestamp", ">", parseInt(lasttimekey)).limit(50).onSnapshot((snapshot)  => {//listener for new messages
            var newmessages = lastchatbackup;
            //console.log("Loaded from backup: ", newmessages)
            var deletedmesssages = [];
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
                if(change.type  === "added"){...
```

`lastchatbackup` is in this case my backup which I'm always saving after a new message arrived (entire chat), also I'm storing the `lasttimekey` which is the timestamp of the most recent message arrived (this is only a `Date.now()` integer, nothing special).

The problem is, if I have 2 devices which do not have the **exact** same time, I'm loading the chat backup **and** loading messages which should not be loaded anymore (because the other phone had another `Date.now()` then the phone I'm using now. Result is, I'm getting duplicates displayed.

This is the reason I can not use Date.now() anymore in my case and why I want to use the `firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`. **However** now I have the problem that I am filtering in my query all messages out which are older then the most recent message in my backup, so I only receive the messages I do not have on my phone in the backup yet.

I can only use strings in the .where() statement in the query, so how I am supposed to filter by the timestamp when I can not properly insert anymore a usual `(Date.now()).toString()` anymore? Is there a way to implement filtering a query based on the timestamp so basically filter out older messages? If there is one, in which format should I parse them into the `.where()` statement in the query call?

Comment: Why not store the `Date.now()` directly then? Also the server timestamp stored can be converted to milliseconds when needed.

Comment: Answer below, but it sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - so I recommend updating your question to explain the actual use-case.

Comment: @Dharmaraj `Date.now()` is based on the client side and different phones will always have an offset, this is the reason I cannot use `Date.now()` anymore.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated the question and implemented the exact usecase and also my thoughts that I had approaching this problem, maybe now it is more clear what my problem is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change how a `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` saves its data, which is as a [`Timestamp` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp). The big difference between the two is that Firestore's `Timestamp` objects have nano-second precision, while JavaScript's `Data.now()` only has millisecond precision.

What you *can* do however it **get** only the milliseconds from the Firestore `Timestamp` object by calling `toMillis()` on it.

Comment: This sounds like a good approach, the problem that I have now is only that Im not able anymore to use `.where()` in my firestore query because (from what I know) I can only insert strings inside there. Is there a way to tell a query to get only documents newer then XX and do not load documents older then YY?

I also updated my post, maybe that helps!

Comment: The **value** part of a `where` can be any allowed type that can exist in the database. You can pass a `Timestamp` there too, which is how you can do timestamp comparisons.

Comment: Thank you again for your help Frank! Restructured my code and my backup saving mechanism and the query works with the `.Timestamp` object!